# Java LDAP with multiple network interface

Tags: java, ldap

I have a server with two NICs and I need to specify which NIC must be used to to connect to a backend LDAP.

I know that in Java the NICs can be specified when a socket is created (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/nifs/definition.html), but how can I do that using the 
JNDI/LDAP framework?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need to do is to obtain control over JNDI's process of creating a socket. For that, you need to tell JNDI which `SocketFactory` to use.

When constructing the `InitialLdapContext`, you can provide a `Hashtable`.

```
Hashtable props = new Hashtable();
props.put("java.naming.ldap.factory.socket", "com.whatever.MySocketFactory");
InitialLdapContext ic = new InitialLdapContext(props, null);
```

When `com.whatever.MySocketFactory` is your own class, extending `javax.net.SocketFactory`.

I think there's a constant somewhere in the JDK for `java.naming.ldap.factory.socket`, but I can't find it...

Answer (score -1):

Or you could use:

```
env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "ldap://<specific IP Address>:636/o=JNDITutorial");
```

-jim

Comment: He is talking about NICs, i.e. local addresses, not target addresses. -1